# Application Master UI not opening, Web proxy is not working properly

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

In my Yarn cluster setup I have Resource Manager HA setup running behind a Load-balancer.

While starting a node manager, I am providing only Load-balancer IP as resource manager address to nodemanager.

Everything else works as expected but Application Master UI is not opening for running applications.

As per my understanding, Application master assumes that request should come from Load-Balancer IP, but actually request is going via Active Resource Manager IP which is not known to Application master hence rejecting the request.

So I was thinking if I can disable the web proxy or I can pass the request to Application master via Load-balancer IP.

Comment: You should **NOT** be using any external load balancers to enable Resource Manager HA in YARN. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html.

Comment: It's not to enable HA.It's to provide single endpoint to clients.Last para of above link explains that.

Comment: Why do you use LB IP in NdeManagers' configuration then? They should use standard HA settings from `yarn-site.xml`.

Comment: So Resource managers are running on kubernetes pods which are ephemeral in nature.Also from nodemanager side now it can be abstracted, and I can run any number of ResourceManager.